# What is classified as an "item.update" in the Podio API?

Tags: api, podio, zapier

I've been building a few workflows using the Podio API & Zapier. A question that I haven't been able to answer is what "item.update" actually means when it comes to a webhook.

I thought that it would trigger (for example) if I had an item that had a field in it called

"Address: 123 Main St"

and I changed that to

"Address: 599 South St"

I figured it would trigger the item.update. It doesn't seem to be doing so. What does item.update actually get triggered by? Also, if that isn't what it triggers - what can I use for my example?

Answer (score 0):

Updating address field will definitely trigger item.update webhook.
In general: any field update will trigger it.

If your webhook is not called, please check the bottom of https://developers.podio.com/examples/webhooks page. There are lots of details and useful information there.